# What is the difference between "" and Nothing in string variables?

Tags: vb.net

I've been using Nothing to initialize a variable to be empty but i find out that we can use "" too so i change all my initial variable to make my code shorter and neat.

But it has the same output ?_?

Comment: I mean i want to initially use a variable with empty value using ex.Dim Name As String = Nothing To Dim Name As String = ""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean string variables in this case. Let's say you have

```
Dim myString As String = Nothing
```

What do you have? You have a declared variable called `myString` but it has literally no value - it is nothing more than a placeholder for where a value *could* go. If you attempt to use this at this point you will get a null reference exception because that's what this is: A null reference. Now let's assume you have this:

```
Dim myString As String = ""    'Or indeed String.Empty
```

What you now have is a defined variable which *actually has a value*. An empty string may not mean much but it is an actual value so you would no longer get a null reference exception if you tried to use it because it isn't a null reference: It is a reference to a **valid value**.

My personal preference is to always ensure that variables of reference types are initialised properly at declaration. using `Nothing` is not initialising in any way - they are `Nothing` by default anyway so you are not changing anything. Use `""` or `String.Empty` (they are functionally equivalent) for string variables, not least because toherwise VS will warn you that you will get a null reference exception if you use the variable before it has had a value set (if you have `Option Strict` on, which IMO you should).

Answer (score 5):

> What is the difference between “” and Nothing on variables?

The difference is that if you initialize a variable to `""`, its value is a blank string. If you initialize it to `Nothing`, its value is `Nothing` (an empty object reference).

You should initialize variables with the appropriate value for what you're using them for. Sometimes that would be `Nothing`, other times `""`, other times `0`, other times `42`. It totally depends on the purpose of the variable.